# How can an object unmark marker interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface

```
class A implements Serializable{

}


class B extends A{
    //this also inherits the marker 

}
```

So is there is a way to **unimplement/unmark** the marker within class `B`?

**Example:** If there are two classes extending `A` named `B` and `C`. But out of them only `C` wants to be serializable and not `B`.

Comment: In my opinion that would be against `ObjectOrientation`.

Comment: If all A instances are not serializable, the A should not be serializable.

Comment: @JBNizet but if source to `A` is not available is there a way to do it? I think a way can be to create a Wrapper class for `B`

Comment: No, it's not possible. As Marko explains, that would be against the basic prociples of inheritance and polymorphism. The best you can do is add a big red statement in the javadoc saying that the class B is in fact not serializable, and that any attempt to serialize a B instance will fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't just that Java is missing support for this: such a feature would completely break down its OOP foundations. Type polymorphism means that one can apply Liskov's substitution principle on subtypes: your "feature" would render it inapplicable.

Every subtype is bound tightly by the contract of the type it extends: at each place one refers to the supertype, an instance of subtype must be able to occur. Therefore if the supertype is serialiable, we cannot allow any subtype not to be.

Answering from a different perspective, if you need functionality from the serializable type `A` in a non-serializable type `B`, then base your design on composition instead of inheritance: let `B` include an appropriate instance of `A`.

Comment: but still wikipedia quotes that this design has faced critique? Is there any specific reason for it?

Comment: Which design, exactly? Please provide a link to the wikipedia content you are referring to.

Comment: The critique is from a different perspective: why did Java design its serialization mechanism with reliance on a marker interface. That is valid critique, specifically because they made the *serializable* property of a class bound by the rules of Liskov's substitution principle.

Comment: true. So there is no answer to it right? Why they designed it this way.

Comment: I don't believe there is any public whitepaper documenting the rationale behind this design, so any attempt at explanation would be just guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, it may make sense to define a marker interface which specifically undoes the effect of another marker interface.  In general, this should only be done in cases where the purpose of the original marker interface is to indicate a potential optimization, and where the marker's documentation has from the beginning always described its antithesis.  In other words, everything that can be done with the base class can be done with the child class (though not necessarily as fast), and no properly-written code will expect the optimization to work on something where it can't.

With regard to things like serialization and cloning, there are three categories of class:

1. Those which don't know of any reason why they can't be serialized (or cloned), but don't make a public promise about that, and thus don't make any promises about descendant classes.  Descendants may be of types 1, 2, or 3.

   Those which can't be serialized, and whose descendants can't be either.  Descendants should all be of type 2.

   Those which publicly promise that they be serialized, with the implication that only classes that can be serialized should derive from them.  Descendants should all be of type 3.

If one recognizes that classes may fall into any of the three categories above, a simple pattern for marker interfaces becomes clear.  Classes with no serialization-marker interface are of type 1.  Those with a "CannotSerialize" marker are type two.  Those with a "CanSerialize" are type three.  No class should implement both markers.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any parts of the Java or .net frameworks which implement that pattern; both seem to assume there are only two types of classes (things that can do something, and those that can't).  Still, it's a good pattern for new types moving forward.